# AllowAllTrustedApps registry key not available in Windows RT

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I have tried to find the registry key

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Appx\AllowAllTrustedApps

in Windows RT and it appears to be missing. I got as far as the Windows folder, but the Appx folder isn't there. Am I missing something? Does the machine need to be connected to a domain to see this part of the registry? Or can I simply add the subfolder and key and expect it to work?

Comment: Never mind. I added the key and value and it worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that adding the key and value works.

1) Make sure the key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Appx exists. If it doesn't, add it.

2) Make sure the 32bit DWORD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Appx\AllowAllTrustedApps exists. If it doesn't, add it.

3) Set the value of that DWORD to 1.

4) Voila! You can now side load your Windows Store App and/or inject a custom data file without a license xml file.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824882.aspx